# What is a definition of $A(P_v)$ in the definition of Brauer-Manin obstruction?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, class-field-theory, definitions

This is a question related to the definition of Brauer-Manin obstruction.

Let $K$ be a number field. $X/K$ be an algebraic variety over $K$.
Let $O_{X,P}$ be a local ring of $X$ at $P$. Let $Br(X)=\bigcap_{P \in X(\overline{K})} Br(O_{X,P})$ be a Brauer group of $X$.

Let $K$ be place of $K$. Let $K_v$ be a  completion of $K$ at $v$. Let $A \in Br(X)$.
For $P \in X(K_v)$, I often encounter a notation $A(P_v)\in Br(K_v)$.
What is a definition of $A(P_v)$ ?

I often encounter this notation in the context of Brauer-Manin obstruction, but I have never seen exact definition of this. Sometimes we call the map $X(K_v)\to Br(K_v)$, $P_v \mapsto A(P_v)$ evaluation map. I don't understand how to make an element of $Br(K_v)$ from rational point of $X$.

(For example, page 18 of this paper, https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/master/2017-2018/ivokok-thesis2.0.pdf)

PS. Thank you very much for your helpful comments.
I explain the definition of Brauer group in this context.
This definition is also explained in the linked paper above.
$Br(O_{X,P})$ is a Brauer group of a local ring. Brauer group of local ring $(R,m)$ is Morita equivalent class of **Azumaya algebra** over $R$.$R$algebra$A$ is Azumaya algebra over $R$ if only if there exists some $n$ and $A \cong R^n$ and $A/mA$ is central simple algebra over $R/m$.

Comment: It uses functoriality of $\operatorname{Br}$: a $K_v$-point of $X$ is a morphism $f \colon \operatorname{Spec} K_v \to X$, so you can look at $f^* A \in \operatorname{Br}(K_v)$ for any $A \in \operatorname{Br}(X)$. The notation is inspired by the same thing for functions: an element $g$ of $\mathcal O_X(X)$ gives by pullback an element of $\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}(K_v)}(\operatorname{Spec}(K_v)) = K_v$, which is the evaluation $g(P)$ of $g$ at $P$. You can do the same for any contravariant functor from schemes to sets.

Comment: Thank you very much. $f$ induces $f^*:Br(X)\to Br(Spec(K_v))$. Why $Br(Spec(K_v))=Br(K_v)$ ?

Comment: @masquerade, on the left $H^2_{ét}$ and on the right $H^2$ Galois cohomology of a complete local field.

Comment: I couldn't help but correct the typos of "Main" for "Manin"...

Comment: @masquerade at this point the question seems to become 'what even is a Brauer group of a scheme and why does it generalise the Brauer group of a field?' This is hard to answer because I don't know what precise definition you're using, but in any case it should be a relatively straightforward unwinding of the definitions (possibly, as F Zaldivar says, by viewing Galois cohomology as a special case of étale cohomology).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I explain the definition of Brauer group in this context. $Br(O_{X,P})$ is a Brauer group of a local ring. Brauer group of local ring $(R,m)$ is equivalent class of Azumaya algebra over $R$. Local ring  $R$ is Azumaya algebra if only if there exists some $n$ and $A \cong R^n$ and $A/mA$ is central simple algebra over $R/m$, and equivalent relation is given by $A~B$ defined as there exists some $m,n$ such that $A \otimes M_m(R)\cong B \otimes M_n(R)$.

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction
The definition of Brauer group you quote from your reference gives you an obvious equality $\text{Br}(\text{Spec} K_v)=\text{Br}(K_v)$ since ${\mathcal O}_{\text{Spec} K_v)}(\text{Spec} K_v))=K_v$, as already remarked by R. van Dobben de Bruyn first comment. However, I believe you need more intuition for the Brauer group in general than what is quoted in the Ms. Thesis you are using. The same goes for the notion of geometric points for schemes. Take a look at an algebraic geometry textbook that uses the "functor of points" approach.

Comment: @F Zaldivar To be honest, I don't understand the notation$Br(SpecK_v)$ you use. $SpecK_v$ is zero ,  what does this notation mean?